# 0x80131040 error at runtime on an included project

Tags: .net, vb.net

Following a move away from Desktops and onto Terminal Server machines, I'm having to recompile a number of projects created by my illustrious predecessor at the company.

One of these projects is a fairly simple WPF MVVM project, with an error-reporting component added as a referenced project, i.e. the reference is to the project, not to a DLL. Both of the projects were started in earlier versions of Visual studio, but both now target framework 4.0 and are being maintained in VS2010.

The whole thing compiles fine, but at runtime I get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'companyName.Tracer, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=0156bfd00d8c2368' or one of its dependencies.
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

The referenced project is signed with a .pfx file, though I have tried compiling with and without the signing, and it appears to make no difference.

I'm not sure where "Version 2.0.0.0" is coming from. The referenced project is at version 1.1.* and the main project is also at 1.1.*.

Presumably I'm missing something obvious, or I've failed to include some vital piece of information, so I'll try to respond to any requests for additional information as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove dependency, recompile DLL project with 4.0, and finally put the dependency back to the first project. It worked for me sometimes...

Comment: Sorry, the referenced project is an explicitly referenced exception catcher. It's referenced every single time my illustrious predecessor thought the program might throw an exception. If I went to the trouble of removing it, I might as well simply add in a real exception handling project...

Comment: As an aside, the only reason I haven't done *that* is because I don't want to go to the trouble of removing all of the error handling, only to find myself with more 0x80131040 errors...

Comment: @Frosty840: error-reporting component does produce a DLL or not? I think it should... no?!? Anyway try to do a Clean on your solution, delete any temporary folder (example obj) and perform a full recompile. Let me know :)

Comment: Sorry, I've deleted both /bin/ and /obj/ and the same error still occurs.

Comment: @Frosty840: user control is written in VB.net or in C++?

Comment: Both projects are written in VB.net

Comment: @Frosty840: I've just created a VB.net app, then added to solution a user-control project and I refereced it in exe project. When I compiled the exe project, it created DLL too... so you must have user-control DLL in your exe project.

Comment: Well, yes, but the reference is not a DLL reference (a reference to a compiled DLL), it is a reference to the actual project. I'm aware that this still generates a DLL

Comment: @Frosty840: ok, that's the first part... Now, recompiling only user-control, can you see DLL file updated? If so, in the exe project remove reference to dll-project, recompile (with errors) and then readd dependency selecting project, finally recompile the EXE. Try...

Comment: I have tried what you said. The error occurs whether the reference is to the project or to the DLL, and it occurs even if I recompile only the exe project, or only the dll project.

Comment: @Frosty840: another question: user-component has some other reference that can be missing? I had the same problem trying to use a user-control referencing a C++ dll which was compiled with VS2008.

Comment: Okay, I have just noticed that this error is occurring *within* companyName.Tracer. There is obviously more wrong here than I was noticing. I think I shall be closing this question and opening a new one once I have more information.

Comment: @Frosty840: so at the end I helped you find the problem... or the project in which the error occurs. Glad to help you :)